# Validation for xeditable input field

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I am working on xeditable plugin. I wanted a suggestion as how i can validate a xeditable input field so that I can disabe and unable the button based on length of the input field.

Comment: Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/N6bQE/57/

Comment: Gandharv it not working for me as i have inline editing.

Comment: well maybe you can use `$watch` and in that function you can set like if `input.length > 15` then `$scope.button` should be disabled